# Exchange Mailbox not correctly created

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I'm creating an exchange 2003 mailbox for an AD user. It has done something, because the exchange tabs are added to the user's properties. However, no mailbox has been added to Exchange server. (it just doesn't appear in the mailbox store). Also, the exchange security settings for this user's mailbox are set incorrectly as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Also, when the user tries to add this Exchange account to his Outlook, he receives the following error:

"Name not found".

Comment: Posting a question to serverfault seems to be enough to fix it. At least I can see a full list of groups and usernames in the exchange security tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any image, but a mailbox will not appear in ESM until the user has logged on to the mailbox or the mailbox has received an email.

Comment: oops, my bad. image fixed.

Comment: Yup, this is normal behaviour of Exchange.

Comment: When you preview the GAL in ESM do you see the user?

Comment: After sending an e-mail to this user, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Always the first thing I do after creating an account is to send it an email and leave it 15 mins. Normally sorts everything out correctly by then.

Answer (score 0):

Are email addresses listed on the email address tab?  If not, then your request is probably queued.

I tell all users that an email box can take up to 24 hours to create.  It depends on how the systems are set to update and how much is going on with your Exchange server when you create the account.  There are times when I create an account and the mailbox is created at the same time, and there are times when it gets stuck in a queue for a few hours.

Typically to force it through, I will have all of the address books rebuild (though I have a small number of email addresses so it only takes a few minutes, it could take hours so consider that beforehand) and then try sending the new account a message.